# CPU core temp MUCH higher than package temp

Tags: cpu, temperature, cpu-temperature

The CPU core temperature is MUCH higher than the package. The core sometime reaches 105 degrees Celsious and the package barely reaches 60 Celsious. Why is that? Will this damage my CPU? I got an AMD A8-6600K.
I use HW monitor.
Sometimes the package temp even reaches 0 degrees and the core temp is like 50 degrees

Comment: Multiple online sources, easily found online, report the max temp for this CPU is far lower than your reported temp. The reported temps WILL damage your cpu. However, multiple online reports also indicate this CPU has a faulty temp sensor.